# For Syntax in Where Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check for multiple conditions with a where clause in Pandas.
Let's say I want the indices of where a row A has the same value as the previous two:

```
df.new = df.index.where(df.A.eq(df.A.shift(1)) & df.A.eq(df.A.shift(2)))
```

This works, but when I do it now for more values, e.g. 1 to 10 or some special numbers like 1, 3, 7, 50, I want to do it more efficient than writing them all down.

I tried something like

```
df.new = df.index.where(df.A.eq(df.A.shift(x)) for x in range(10)))
```

but this does not work.
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) with `reduce`:

```
m = np.logical_and.reduce([df.A.eq(df.A.shift(x)) for x in range(1, 11)])
df.new = df.index.where(m)
```